# Bigchaindb 2.2.2 error installing while building gevent

Tags: cython, gevent, bigchaindb

```
Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      cdef load_traceback
      cdef Waiter
      cdef wait
      cdef iwait
      cdef reraise
      cpdef GEVENT_CONFIG
            ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      src/gevent/_gevent_cgreenlet.pxd:181:6: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
      Compiling src/gevent/greenlet.py because it changed.
```

I'm using ubuntu and getting this error while trying to install bigchaindb.

I'm following the tutorial at [Bigchaindb docs](https://docs.bigchaindb.com/en/latest/installation/node-setup/set-up-node-software.html#) and already using the latest version of pip

Comment: You're builing an old version of gevent, you need to update. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1801.

Comment: I guess you don't have any control over which `gevent` version is getting selected. Either bigchaindb or one of its dependencies has gevent pinned to an old version, probably.

Comment: An older version of Cython will also work - `cpdef` attributes were deprecated (but still work) in the 0.29.x branch, and removed in the 3.0 alpha branch. Essentially because they were just `cdef` attributes so didn't really do what anyone expected